# How to use a Vue component from an external library (for example Vue Cal) in a .NET Core Razor Page?

Tags: vue.js, .net-core, razor, razor-pages, unpkg

Hello dear people of Stack Overflow.

I am currently playing around with the combination of .NET Core Razor Pages and the VueJS JavaScript framework. I would like to use the [Vue Cal](https://antoniandre.github.io/vue-cal/) library to display a calendar view on my Razor Page.

For simplicity I am pulling Vue from a CDN in the _Layout.cshtml file as most tutorials suggest, so I figured I could also pull in Vue Cal like this. The head tag of my _Layout.cshtml looks as follows:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - RazorVue</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/RazorVue.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.2.1/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-cal"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/vue-cal/dist/vuecal.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

My question now is, how do I go on to use the Vue Cal component in one of my Razor pages? I have tried it as follows, but the calendar won't show:

```
@page
@model RazorVue.Pages.CalendarModel
@{
}

<div id="calendar">
    <vue-cal style="height: 250px" />
</div>

 @section Scripts {
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-cal"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         Vue.createApp({
             components: { VueCal: vuecal }
         }).mount('#calendar')
     </script>
 }
```

My knowledge of both Razor Pages and Vue is still quite limited so I would appreciate it if you guys could help me out with this issue. It doesn't have to be Vue Cal specifically, I just want to learn how to use component libraries in this context. Thanks in advance :-)

EDIT: I changed the Razor Page code above and for clarity, I'll post my full _Layout.cshtml below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - RazorVue</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/RazorVue.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.2.1/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-cal"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/vue-cal/dist/vuecal.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">RazorVue</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Counter">Counter</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/CatFacts">Cat facts</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Calendar">Calendar</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2023 - RazorVue - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>

    <script>
    // Check that service workers are supported
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        // Use the window load event to keep the page load performant
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js');
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplest way.

You will need to put your Vue App in the `Script Section`.

In the `_Layout.cshtml` file there should be a `Script Section` defined:

```
 @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

or async

```
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
```

And on your Razor Page

- define the app container for `Vue App` and put `Vue Cal` component inside
- put the `Vue App` instantiation in the `Script Section`

  ```
   @section Scripts {

       <script type="text/javascript">
           Vue.createApp({
               components: { VueCal: vuecal }
           }).mount('#app')
       </script>
   }
  ```

You can also put the `Vue Cal` script tag directly to your Razor Page, if you don't want to load it on every page of your web application.

```
@section Scripts {
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-cal"></script>
....
```

There are also other ways to achieve the same result. But at the end you will need to load some JavaScript file on your Razor Page where is your `Vue App` stored.

Comment: Could you please look at the edit of my question, am I missing something?

Comment: You should put the `script` tag into the `html body` tag. There should be no tags after `</html>`. And you could also put the service worker part into the `js/site.js`

Comment: I have found out what went wrong! I was still using Vue 2 and after some research online I found out that the Vue.createApp syntax only works in Vue 3. I rewrote my code to support Vue 3 and pulled the right package from the CDN and now my calendar displays as intended! I'll mark your answer as accepted and thank you for the helpfulness :-)

Comment: You are trying to use Vue Cal v4 (for Vue v3) with Vue v2. Use Vue Cal v3 (https://unpkg.com/vue-cal@legacy) or switch to Vue v3.